# What can I do to avoid impedance discontinuity when high-speed signal bifurcates on PCB?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, impedance

As mentioned before, I want to supply two PCBs with same-frequency clock(as high as 10GHz).But now there is only one pair of differential clock, while both of the PCBs need one.

So I am thinking of using an extra PCB, whose task is to distribute one clock into two. However, this involves a bifurcation for the high-frequency clock, inevitably causing impedance discontinuity.Is there any better way to deal with this?

Comment: You could buffer the clock, or use an RF splitter maybe.

Comment: I think using a clock distribution IC might work. I don't know that much about differential signals, but perhaps going to single ended, using something like a Wilkinson splitter and then going back to differential could work.

Comment: Yeah. I found a few clock buffer IC's on digikey that can handle up to 10 GHz differential clocks. That is the best bet.

Comment: @mkeith can you give me the link? thanks!

Comment: @mkeith I haven't found ones that can handle such high frequency.

Comment: clock distribution IC FTW

Comment: @mkeith If clock buffer IC is to be used, I have to use those single-input, differential-output ones.

Comment: @Neil Too expensive?

Comment: I am not sure what country you are in. But I found it easily at digikey searching for "clock buffers" and then selecting clock distribution, and then selecting speed of 10 GHz and above. One example is onsemi p/n NBSG11MNHTBG. http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/NBSG11-D.PDF

Comment: In theory, you can maintain continuous impedance if you change the impedance to double at the point where the lines split. For best results, you would also want to keep the length after split equal, and make sure both ends are terminated under all conditions. So you could run 50 Ohm differential impedance up to the split point, then run each leg at 100 Ohm differential impedance from split to load. Never done this, not sure it will work.